# Why this form in html is not submitting?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I don't understand why, but when I open the html file where the form is I fill all the gaps and then click on the submit button, but anything happens.

```
<form method="post" action="PHP FILE">
<label>NAME*</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="YOUR NAME">
<label>EMAIL*</label>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL”>
<label>CATEGORY*</label>
<select name="category">
<option value="1">FIRST</option>
<option value="2">SECOND</option>
</select>
<label>PHONE*</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="YOUR PHONE">
<label>WEBSITE</label>
<input type="text" name="web" placeholder="YOUR WEBSITE”>
<label>MESSAGE</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is no valid action `action="PHP FILE"`. You have to provide a valid URI or URL to send the form to.

Comment: Yes, I know it! In the real form is action="../assets/send.php"

Comment: Do you have any JS active on that page?

Comment: What do you mean with "in the web yes"?

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of scripts.

Comment: They probably prevent your form from sending to the server. If you for example have registered a `$('from').on('submit', function() { return false; });` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes of placeholder is differing
Make sure they are same

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL”>

<input type="text" name="web" placeholder="YOUR WEBSITE”>
```

Comment: To be exact: They have to be `"` and not `”`

Comment: Oh don't worry about that, because when I copied the code I changed some words to make it intelligible because I'm not english.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER It's something about the JS in the page, because I put the code in a nother file and it works.

Comment: I don't understand anything, when I erase one script, no matter what script is, only one, it works...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND"/>
```

The action of the form must be some file
Like abc.php or abc.html

I hope this must work

Comment: This is exact the same. As `<button type="submit">SEND</button>`.